# How to differentiate between an empty string and non-existing value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I have an HTML like this:

```
<input type="text" id="a" value="" />
<input type="text" id="b" />
```

If I do a `$("#a").val()` I cannot distinguish if exists a value and this is empty or if no value exists. Is there any way to distinguish these two cases?

Comment: What's the practical difference?

Comment: I have a "date" input that must set to today date iff don't have any value. In case it has a value="" it must remain empty

Comment: Note that none of the posted solutions work in IE8...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can check for the existence of the `value` attribute.

`$('#a[value]')` this means to find the element with id `a` that also has an attribute `value`

If you want to check after you have selected the element, if it has a `value` attribute then

```
var elem = $('#a');
if ( elem.is('[value]') ) {
  // it has a value attribute
}
```

Comment: This will give a false positive in IE7 and lower where the attribute doesn't exist, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$( '#a' ).is( '[value]' ) // true
$( '#b' ).is( '[value]' ) // false
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/w8gFF/1/

Comment: Have you checked that is various versions of IE?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: weird - I would have expected it to work in IE 8, which supports `hasAttribute()`.  IE 7 and lower don't support `hasAttribute` and, even worse, the `attributes` collection is pre-populated with a list of possible attributes.

Comment: @AndyE IE9 implements `hasAttribute`, but not IE8 - [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Document_Object_Model%29).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Wikipedia fails again - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304121(v=vs.85).aspx.  I had already tested it and it's definitely there in IE 8.

Comment: @Andy Aha OK. I only have IE9 on my machines and I can confirm that it fails in IE9 Compatibility View.

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of IE don't support `hasAttribute`, and as [Šime Vidas discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807604/how-to-differentiate-between-an-empty-string-and-non-existing-value/7807654#7807654) even jQuery can't be trusted on those browsers.

The way I had to do it when I needed something similar in an older version of IE was:

```
function hasAttribute(el, attr) {   
    if ("hasAttribute" in el)
        return el.hasAttribute(attr);

    else if ("outerHTML" in el) {
        return (el.outerHTML
                   // remove content
                   .replace(el.innerHTML, "")
                   // remove attribute values with quotes
                   .replace(/=(?:(["'])[^\1]*\1)?/, " ")
                   // remove attribute values without quotes
                   .replace(/=[^\s>]+/, "")
                   // normalize
                   .toLowerCase()
                   // search for attribute
                   .indexOf(" " + attr.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    }
}
```

In your case, you might use this function like so:

```
var hasValue = hasAttribute($("a")[0], "value");
```

Unfortunately, this still isn't very robust in Internet Explorer 8 and lower.  False positives and negatives will be returned in those browsers for various attributes and, unfortunately, I don't believe there's a workaround.

Comment: +1, cool workaround. It would miss attributes without a value.. (*like `multiple` for `select` elements, `checked` for radio/check boxes etc..*) but it seems great ! maybe using a regex for the last part would make it more powerful..

Comment: @Gaby: indeed, I'd not thought about boolean attributes.  Non-boolean attributes are normalized if you leave off the value and I think that's what threw me off.  Looks like I'll have to write a regex and update the code I'm using... :-)

Comment: Thinking about it, such a regex would probably give a false positive if the name of the attribute was included in any other attribute's value.  Since this piece of code is fine for the question, I'll leave it as is and see if I can get a more robust workaround in the project I have.

Comment: This is not working on Internet EXplorer 8.0. hasAttribute(el, "value") is returning always false for `<input value="">`

Comment: @Ivan: you're right, it looks like there's a bug in IE 8 where it returns false for attributes that are defined but empty.  I've changed the code and *quickly* tested it in IE 8 and it worked well.  I don't have the time to be more thorough until Monday, but I can't foresee any problems with it.  I hope it fixes the problem for you, anyway.

Comment: My quick test on home computer has failed :( I'll test again to confirm

Comment: Hmm.  I'll take another look when I get some time.  I could always add in IE 8 detection but I'd prefer not to if I can help it.

Comment: @Ivan: I tested potential solutions quite thoroughly and I believe there is no workaround for IE 8 and lower on those attributes. Sorry!  I did improve the overall function, though, it works for Boolean attributes now.

Answer (score 1):

It's good question, but I think **you will not get any workaround in IE8 or early**. I think so after some experiments which I made. By the way one can make the experiments with the IE9 or IE10 beta which one has installed. One should just uses `meta` "X-UA-Compatible" to change the Document Compatibility Mode (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325.aspx)).

I tested with:

```
document.getElementById("a").outerHTML = "<input type='text' id='a' value='' />";
alert(document.getElementById("a").outerHTML);
```

and the `alert(document.getElementById("a").outerHTML)` only:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
</head>

<body>
    <fieldset><input type="text" id="a" value="" /></fieldset>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        //document.getElementById("a").outerHTML = '<input type="text" id="a" value="" />';
        alert('In IE7 outerHTML for <input type="text" id="a" value="" />:\n' +
            document.getElementById("a").outerHTML);
    //]]>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In case of "IE=8" the code above displays the text `"<INPUT id=a type=text>"`. If we would change the value of `"X-UA-Compatible"` to "IE=7" we will see even `"<INPUT id=a">`. The same code with "IE=edge" displays `<input id="a" value="" type="text">`. The corresponding demos are here: [IE=edge](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/JavaScript/IE9attributes.html), [IE=8](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/JavaScript/IE8attributes.html), [IE=7](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/JavaScript/IE7attributes.html).

So it seems that IE do some kind of "optimization" during parsing of HTML. The order and the case of attributes which will be get by `outerHTML` is different as in original code. IE parse HTML code with "optimization" and what we see later has no more `value=""`. So no tricks of jQuery can help us to get no more existing attribute.